# Is there a default circular blueprint cut depth?

Tags: technical-drawing

I have a drawing that has a circular cut:
[image: circular cut]

Nowhere it says how deep should the cut go into the material.

Is there a default way to obtain the depth that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Are there any auxiliary views?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be a through-cut, however we can see that isn't the case. My next guess would be a spherical radius but unless the spherical center is clearly defined that's not helpful and either way it wouldn't be good practice.

I think generally the answer is no, there's not a default unless it's clear from the context what it should be and the fact that you're asking here indicates that it isn't. If possible, I'd try to talk to whoever made the print for more clarification. Also, depending on where you work, different conventions might be used or some context might be implied.

Further, that dimension only indicates a property of that specific feature, and it appears to be dimensioned off of a section view that may or may not lie on any major plane.

It's possible that this dimension is still useful in conjunction with other dimensions and views, but might benefit from being changed to provide better clarity.